# Can't find command installed from 'go get github.com/...'

Tags: bash, git, google-chrome, go, package

I'm having trouble figuring out how to install the gen-bundle commands from this library:
https://github.com/WICG/webpackage/tree/master/go/bundle

I've already checked that I installed the go library correctly, and have it in my environment variable. But it still says 'command not found' when I try to run 'gen-bundle' in my bash terminal.

Will someone please explain what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Please show an actual install command and the output of `env` command.

Comment: Read about PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Check the variables set using the command `go env`. It'll have a similar output like this:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
...
// More vars
```

If you've used `go install` for installation as `go install github.com/...` builds the binaries and keeps them in a defined path. You'll find your executables in:

```
$(GOBIN)/bin
```

or

```
~/go/bin/
```

If you've found your desired path, then you can append that path to `PATH` env. For example:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"
```

Comment: I needed this one - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"